# Quota increase is not reflected in the AI platform machines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

My request for a quota increase for Nvidia A100 GPUs was approved. But for some stage reason, it is not reflected in the AI platform machines, while using notebooks.

In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fzlx.png) we see that the quota increase was approved for me for europe-west4, but the machine region is not available at my AI platform instances [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTI1T.png).

Is there an additional intermediate step missing in order to use the device?

- [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fzlx.png):
  [Compute Engine API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fzlx.png)
- [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTI1T.png):
  [AI platform - Notebook instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTI1T.png)

Comment: We will be adding support to this region the next quarter.

Comment: What is an alternative way for running AI processes on this device? So far I was only using the AI platform notebooks to do so.

Comment: Try creating a DLVM which is the base of Notebooks, (just not controlled by Notebooks API but by Compute Engine API) Once we support this region you can just use Notebooks register method. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/registering-legacy-notebooks?authuser=2&_ga=2.20177791.-672956794.1526786709

Answer (score 1):

Currently, AI Notebooks are not available in europe-west4. You can confirm it by using the following command,

`gcloud beta notebooks locations list`

You will see that ***europe-west4*** is not in the list.

However, there is an open Feature Request to add this region, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162213380). You can go to the page, click on **+1** to indicate it affects you and post a comment there. Then follow the issue tracker case for any updates.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg if you find the information I shared useful, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gcloud beta compute instances create a100-test1 \
--zone=europe-west4-a \
--machine-type=a2-megagpu-16g \
--subnet=default \
--network-tier=PREMIUM \
--maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
--accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-a100,count=16 \
--image-family=tf-latest-gpu \
--image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
--metadata="proxy-mode=mail,proxy-user-mail=user@domain.com"
```

You can try different A2 model/image family/A100 cores